# MS Charts showing wrong X Axis values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I have one chart control with two buttons.First call candlestick chart.Second call bar chart.If I call only one of them everything is fine.But if I click the button for bar chart it gets the X Axis values from the candlestick chart.Bar chart X Axis should be from 0-15.

How they look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA79F.jpg

On formload candlestick chart is loaded first.Everything is still fine.
When Close/Open button for the bar chart is clicked.Its left with the X Axis values from candlestick chart.

When I click Chart button for the candlestick chart after hitting Close/Open.
Y Axis values are missing now.

Methods for calling the charts:

```
 public void CandleStickChartMain()
    {
        // clear the chart
        if (ChartCandle.Series.Count > 0) this.ChartCandle.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        this.ChartCandle.Series.Clear();
        this.ChartCandle.Titles.Clear();


        //Clear Grid
        ChartCandle.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        ChartCandle.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

        //Series
        ChartCandle.Series.Add("Date");
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].YValuesPerPoint = 4;
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].XValueMember = "Day";
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close";
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=Green";
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
        ChartCandle.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;
        ChartCandle.Series["Date"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;

        //Axis Y Minimum 
        ChartCandle.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = Open.Min() - (Open.Min() / 50);

        //Data Binding
        ChartCandle.DataSource = ChartDataTable;
        ChartCandle.DataBind();

    }


public void BarChart()
    {

        // clear the chart
        if (ChartCandle.Series.Count > 0) this.ChartCandle.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        this.ChartCandle.Series.Clear();
        this.ChartCandle.Titles.Clear();

        // Set palette
        this.ChartCandle.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Excel;

        // Set title
        this.ChartCandle.Titles.Add("Price Data Open/Close");

        //Add series
        //Series Open
        var seriesOpen = ChartCandle.Series.Add("Open");
        for (int i = 0; i < Open.Length; i++)
        {

            seriesOpen.Points.Add(Open[i]);
        }
        //Series Close
        var SeriesClose = ChartCandle.Series.Add("Close");
        for (int i = 0; i < Close.Length; i++)
        {
            SeriesClose.Points.Add(Close[i]);
        }

        var chartAreaOpenClose = ChartCandle.ChartAreas[seriesOpen.ChartArea];

        // Zoom and scroll options
        // set view range to [0,max]
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.Maximum = Open.Length + 1;

        // enable autoscroll
        chartAreaOpenClose.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;

        // let's zoom to [0,blockSize] (e.g. [0,100])
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        int position = 0;
        int size = 15;
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size);

        // disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

        // set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
        chartAreaOpenClose.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 15;

        // additional
        ChartCandle.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;

    }
```

Comment: for me, adding a `Candlestick` or `Stock` type chart to a ChartArea breaks `Axis.IsStartedFromZero=false` behaviour.